# Is OpenGL ES 2.0 the standard in Android Game Development?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, lag

I have spent a few dozen man hours searching Google and asking questions on forums trying to figure out whether or not my OpenGL ES 2.0 application on Android is lagging due to errors on my end, a virus on my device, OpenGL implementation on Android, or OpenGL implementation on the Samsung Galaxy Express.

I have found nothing, if anyone wants to try answer that root issue I would greatly appreciate it, but my question is if I should revert back to OpenGL ES 1.0 and if that is what everyone else uses.

The exact same application (single spinning triangle) using the exact same timestep with the only difference being a barebones OpenGL ES 1.0 vs OpenGL ES 2.0 change causes stuttering in the 2.0 app and smooth animation in the 1.0 app.

Do other games only use 1.0?  If they use 2.0 can you point me to an example that is known to cause no noticeable stuttering, that I may download and test on my device?  I have downloaded the OpenGL ES 2.0 sample from Google themselves, stutters the same.

Does Samsung Galaxy Express not handle OpenGL ES 2.0 gracefully?  Is there any way to get another Android device without stealing or asking random strangers, I have no money.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that OpenGL ( not just ES ) is a specification, the other part the implementation is not governed by anyone, well by the specification to a certain extent meaning that the implementations can differ greatly altho they shouldn't.
This is due to the fact that OpenGL uses client drivers to handle the commands and those are written by the GPU creators ( usually ). For PCs you can easily name all the prominent GPU builders, nVidia and ATI so there you can at least know what to expect.

For phones there are lots of GPU/CPU combos so more errors to be discovered due to faulty or wrong form the start designs, not just the GPU's drivers, since the phone's creator may also make changes to the system or use low speed/grad parts which will result in poor performance.

OpenGL ES 1.0 I would say is more common since 2.0, mainly because it's backwards compatible so a device that supports 2.0 will most certainly support 1.0 as well. For development you can skip the whole "build on phone" thing by making a framework and using an emulator ( OpenGL ES ) on PC and when you are done just copy over your OpenGL code into your phone app.

Since manufactures try to keep their costs low, they tend to lie about what they actually do, or support so ES 1.0 being more simple and hard-wired than 2.0 it is possible that the lag may be due to the poorly supported OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [Android Platform Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL), Open GL 2.0 makes up 98.3% of devices that visited the Play Store in the last 7 days, making it the standard for game development.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a lot of people seem to have trouble with the OpenGL ES drivers for Samsung Android devices.  You should try another device with a different graphics core.

Since Ice Cream Sandwich, the Android platform itself mostly uses OpenGL ES 2.0, including major components, such as the SurfaceFlinger.  It's not optional anymore.  Check out [this article.](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1)